# Close CSS only lightbox by clicking background without using Js

Tags: php, html, css

I want to add a functionality for my lightbox, so that it closes also when clicking the background.

At present it closes on clicking the close button. But it should also close on clicking the background and not on clicking the inner contents of the lightbox.

I have a form inside my lightbox so making it close on clicking anywhere in the lightbox doesn't work for my requirement.

Is there any way I could do this using only CSS or PHP as this functionality is to be added in a wordpress website.

**This is my lightbox example:**

```
    <a href="#lightboxCustom">Click here</a> 

    <div id="lightboxCustom">
            <div class="lightboxCustomDiv">
            <a class="close" href="#_"><span style="color: #fff;">X</span></a>
            <center><h2>Title</h2><br></center>
            <p>Content </p>
            <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type= "submit>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.lightboxCustom:target {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
}

.lightboxCustom{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: No..."clicks" **require** Javascript.

Comment: _“At present it closes on clicking the close button.”_ - and that works based on what, exactly? Correct, clicking an actual link, that changes the URL fragment, so that the `:target` pseudo class does not apply to the lightbox any more. So the solution is pretty obvious, is it not? Use another such link, and place it _behind_ your lightbox, covering the full screen, so that it “catches” all clicks outside the lightbox …

Comment: @04FS  The problem is I have placed the div to cover the entire screen and set the background color to grey. And the pop-up is now over this div and its z-index is higher than that of the background div. So enclosing that with the anchor tag is not working like I did with the close button. I used <a href="#_">Close</a> for the close button. The anchor tag works only when the div its enclosed in is having a higher z-index.

Comment: See my answer for a basic example of how easily this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another such link, and place it behind your lightbox, covering the full screen, so that it “catches” all clicks outside the lightbox.

I moved the background color from your outer to your inner div element - so that the link can “sit between” the two, and cover everything that is not covered by the inner div.

You’ll probably want to add some more formatting to get the inner element nicely centered in the container etc., but the basic principle works. (The close link outside has a solid red background here, for demonstration purposes.)

```css
.lightboxCustom:target {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}

.lightboxCustom {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.lightboxCustominner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.close-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lightboxCustom">Click here</a>

<div class="lightboxCustom" id="lightboxCustom">
  <a class="close-bg" href="#_"></a>
  <div class="lightboxCustominner">
    <a class="close" href="#_"><span style="color: #fff;">X</span></a>
    <center>
      <h2>Title</h2><br></center>
    <p>Content </p>
    <form>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you have a darkening background around your lightbox, right? If you want to make it CSS only, I would suggest making the background div a sibling.

```html
<div class="lightboxCustom">
  <div class="lightboxCustominner">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lightboxBackdrop">
</div>
```

```css
.lightboxBackdrop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

  //you need to play with z-index to make it look right
  z-index: 0;
}

.lightboxCustom {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.lightboxCustom:target {
  display: block;
}
.lightboxCustom:target + .lightboxBackdrop {
  display: block;
}
```

I've never done anything like this and have no idea, how it well it works for accessibility.

Comment: The closing click using <a href="#_"><<div class="lightboxBackdrop"></div>  is only working when the z-index of the background is higher than that of the lightbox. With the lower value of z-index <a> tag isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        a.lightbox img {
            height: 150px;
            border: 3px solid white;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            margin: 94px 20px 20px 20px;
        }
        .lightbox-target {
            position: fixed;
            top: -100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .lightbox-target img {
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom: 0;
            max-height: 0%;
            max-width: 0%;
            border: 3px solid white;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        }
        a.lightbox-close {
            display: block;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: white;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: -80px;
            right: 0;
            -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        }
        a.lightbox-close:before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            width: 1px;
            background: black;
            position: absolute;
            left: 26px;
            top:10px;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);
        }
        a.lightbox-close:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            width: 1px;
            background: black;
            position: absolute;
            left: 26px;
            top:10px;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            transform:rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .lightbox-target:target {
            opacity: 1;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .lightbox-target:target img {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
            top: 0px;
        }
        .lightboxCustom {
            margin-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="lightbox" href="#goofy">
        Click here
    </a> 
    <div class="lightbox-target" id="goofy">
        <div class="lightboxCustom" id="lightboxCustom">
            <div class="lightboxCustominner">
                <center>
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                    <br>
                </center>
                <p>Content </p>
                <form>
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.lightbox-target .lightboxCustom').click(function(){
            $('.lightbox-target').css({
                opacity: 0,
                zIndex: 1
            });   
        });

        $('a').click(function(){
            $('.lightbox-target#goofy').css({
                opacity: 1,
                zIndex: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. But I am looking for a way without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine just needed some css styling.

```css
.lightboxCustom:target {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
}

.lightboxCustom{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
}
.lightboxCustominner {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.close {
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lightboxCustom">Click here</a> 
<div class="lightboxCustom" id="lightboxCustom">
    <div class="lightboxCustominner">
        <a class="close" href="#_">X</a>
        <center><h2>Title</h2><br></center>
        <p>Content </p>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type= "submit>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```